# How to use encryption in ydn-db database library?

Tags: client-side, ydn-db, encryption

I am trying to implement setSecret to encrypt the values in indexeddb but get the error:

**"unable to call method setSecret of undefined"**

Code Below:

```
 $(window).load(function () {

   //Database Schema
    var db_schema = {
    stores: [
        {
            name: "Employees",
        }
    ]
}

var secret = "Test";
db.setSecret(secret); 

    db = new ydn.db.Storage('Database', db_schema);

});
```

Following the [link](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/using/encryption.html), but not sure where I'm going wrong any ideas:

Anyone encrpyted there indexddb values before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Database Creation
    //Database Schema
        var db_schema = {
            stores: [{
                name: "DataTable",
                encrypted: true
            }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            Encryption: {
                //expiration: 1000 * 15, //  optional data expiration in ms.
                secrets: [{
                    name: 'aaaa',
                    key: 'aYHF6vfuGHpfWS*eRLrPQxZjSó~É5c6HjCscqDqRtZasp¡JWSMGaW'
                }]
            }
        };



        //Create the database with the relevant tables using the schema above
        db = new ydn.db.Storage('Database', db_schema,options);   


$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/home/DownloadData",
                        data: { File: file },
                        success: function (result) {

                             var Key = result.Data.Key;
                             var DownloadedData= {
                                 Data: result.Data,
                                 Data1: result.Data1,
                                 Data2: result.Data2,
                                Data3: result.Data3
                             };
                             db.put('DataTable', DownloadedData, Key);
                             return false;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert("fail");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: The object DownloadedData has a number of objects that have a number of arrays in them. Those arrays then have a number of objects inside them.

Comment: I have only added the following script to my project:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ydn.db-isw-core-crypt-qry-dev.js"></script> am I supposed to use (-crypt" module ) or add it somewhere?

Comment: It works with a number of objects but the Data3 is very large is there  any way of splitting the data: result in to objects? It falls over because it is saving the whole object as Data and it exceeds the maximum.

Comment: Just quick note, your setting make data expire after 15 s.

Comment: Just one file. It has crypt module

Comment: Large object should be OK as long as it can be serialized with JSON serailizer. So please do serialization just before inserting, `DownloadedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(DownloadedData));` If JSON serialization fail, you need to split data.

Comment: Unable to stringify the object as its too large, will see how to split the data

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for documentation behind. I have updated the [documentation](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/using/encryption.html). Now you have to put encryption key in database options.

```
var schema = {
    version: 1,
    stores: [{
      name: 'encrypt-store',
      encrypted: true
    }]
};
var options = {
  Encryption: {
    expiration: 1000*15, //  optional data expiration in ms.
    secrets: [{
      name: 'aaaa',
      key: 'aYHF6vfuGHpfWSeRLrPQxZjS5c6HjCscqDqRtZaspJWSMGaW'
    }]
  }
};

var db = new ydn.db.Storage('encrypted-db-name', schema, options);
```

You have to use ["-crypt" module](https://storage.cloud.google.com/ydn-db-d1/0.8.9/ydn.db-isw-core-crypt-qry-dev.js) to get that feature. It supports transparent data encryption using sha256 crypto, per record salting and key rotation. You still need server to generate encryption key and send to the client securely. There is also a [demo app](http://yathit.github.io/sample-encryption/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have implemented the above using your example so I know the encryption works. But when I try to store an object that has a number of objects with in it I get the following error in the script: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: could you share your code? the library work for any number of objects.